# Действие после скачивания файла

Tags: php, javascript

Создал скрипт скачивания файла, который перенаправляет пользователя на страницу обработки файла и сразу после скачивает его выводя диалоговое окно.

Вопрос в том как определить что загрузка файла началась или диалоговое окно закрыто или что-либо что бы запустить переход на главную страницу?

Так я запускаю загрузку файла:

```
<script>location.replace("/download.php?file='.$name.'");</script>
```

А в `download.php` все по стандартному взятое [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно открыть загрузку файла в отдельном окне/вкладке, и проверять когда оно будет закрыто.

Пример:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function openTab(url, callback){
        var popup = window.open(url, "_blank");
        if(typeof callback == 'function'){
            var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                try {
                    if (popup == null || popup.closed) {
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                        callback();
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                }
            }, 500);
        }
        popup.focus();
    }

    //JS
    document.getElementById('link-download').onclick = function (event){
        openTab(event.target.href, function(){
            /* Действия после старта скачивания */
            window.location.reload();
        });
        return false;
    } 

    //jQuery
    $(document).on('click', '.download-file', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        openTab(event.target.href, function(){
            /* Действия после старта скачивания */
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="/download.php?file='<?php echo $name;?>'" id="link-download" class="download-file">Скачать</a>
```

Если в файле `download.php` возникли проблемы, или файл не найден, и вы хотите закрыть новое окно/вкладку, то можно просто вывести:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>if(window.opener){window.close();}</script>";
```

P.S. Используйте один из вариантов или с `jQuery` framework или на чистом `js`, оба не оставляйте.

P.S.S. Пример, для примера, копирование-вставка может не сработать.

P.S.S.S. Метод отслеживания закрытие окна может и не сработать.

Comment: В общем я так понял иначе отследить нельзя? Ибо этот вариант действительно не очень надежный...